# Mysql stored procedure called successfully but no output records shown

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, call, wamp, procedures

I have used the following code to create a procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE procedure GetBooksbyBorrowerID (IN Bor_id VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN
SELECT borrower_details.Borrower_ID ,borrower_details.Book_ID, book_mst.book_Title,book_mst.LANGUAGE, borrower_details.borrowed_from_date 
FROM borrower_details 
JOIN book_mst
ON borrower_details.BOOK_ID = book_mst.ISBN
WHERE (borrower_details.borrower_id = 'Bor_id');
END //
```

When I call this procedure, it says Mysql query executed successfully, but does not show the output records. And there are records in the database that match the criteria in the query. I use the following statement to call:

```
CALL GetBooksbyBorrowerID ('BOR001');
```

What should I do to view the output records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing **borrower_details.borrower_id** with the string **'Bor_id'** and not the parameter.

Use `WHERE (borrower_details.borrower_id = Bor_id);`